# Update multiple choice field in sharepoint using rest api

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am trying to update the multiple choice field in sharepoint online using rest api. I am getting 401 bad request error.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("XXXXX/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/Sample/TestDoc.docx')/ListItemAllFields/");

string stringData = 
@"{'__metadata': { 'type':'SP.ListItem' }, 
'TestColumn': { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)', results: ['Test1']}}}";

request.ContentLength = stringData.Length;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(stringData);
writer.Flush();

 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the payload is *invalid* in your example:

```
string stringData = 
@"{'__metadata': { 'type':'SP.ListItem' }, 
'TestColumn': { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)', results: ['Test1']}}}";
```

The point is the type `SP.ListItem` corresponds to `Generic` list, in your example it is a *Documents* library.

So, a *valid* *entity type name* needs to be provided, you could utilize the following endpoint to determine `metadata type`:

Endpoint:

```
Url: /_api/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
Method: GET
```

Secondly, the Update operation requires the following properties to be specified with request:

- Create an HTTP request using the `POST` verb.
- Add an `X-HTTP-Method` header with a value of MERGE.
- Add an `If-Match` header with a value of the entity’s original ETag.

You could refer [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api/) for a more details.

And last but no least, `Content-Type` and `Accept` request headers needs to be specified (follow [this article](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) for a more details), for example:

```
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
```

---

The following example summarizes it and demonstrates how to update multi-choice field value:

```
var requestUrl = $"{webUrl}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{fileUrl}')/ListItemAllFields";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Credentials = GetCredentials(userName, password);
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestVal);
request.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");


var payload = @"{
                        '__metadata': { 'type':'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem' },
                        '<ColumnName>': { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: ['Val1']}
        }";

request.ContentLength = payload.Length;
var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(payload);
writer.Close();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```