# why 'PrimitiveValue' or 'StartObject' node was expected error

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint Online:

I have a form that has a few multi-select choice fields.  When I try to add an item, I get the following error:

> "value: "A node of type 'StartArray' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read a value of a property; however, a 'PrimitiveValue' or 'StartObject' node was expected."

Here's the code and the fields that are multi-select.

```
 $.ajax({
url: fullUrl,
method: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.AuditItem' },
  'Register': that.register,
  'RiskRegister': that.nextIndex,
  'Reopen': that.formatDate(that.reopen),
  'RiskOrIssue': that.riskOrIssue,
  'Locations': that.locations,               //<---multi-select choice field
  'ProblemT': that.probTitle,
  'ProblemStatement': that.problemStatement,
  'TaskOwner': that.taskOwner,
  'RiskOwner': that.riskOwner,
  'Auditor': that.auditor    //<--- multi-select choice field
}),
headers: {
  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
},
success: function(){
  alert("Item Added!");
},
error: function(data){
  console.log(data);
}   
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-select choice field value needs to set with a collection, here is a code snippet for your reference:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var locations = ['Locations1','Locations3'];
       var Auditors =  ['Auditor1','Auditor3'];
       var item = {  
                    "__metadata": {  
                        "type": 'SP.Data.MyListListItem'
                    },  
                       "Title":'Test',
                       "Locations": { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: locations },
                       "Auditor": { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: Auditors }


                };    
  $.ajax({  
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",  
                    method: "POST",  
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                    data: JSON.stringify(item),  
                    async: false,  
                    headers: {  
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
                    },  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        alert('The Request has been successfully Added'); 
                    },  
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                        alert('Error');  
                    }  
                });  
</script>
```

[image]

Reference:

[Update multiple choice field in sharepoint using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027004/update-multiple-choice-field-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api)

Comment: You are hard coding the array values and it's working.  When I do it this way  ``` "Locations": { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: that.locations},``` it doesn't work.   ```that.locations``` contains an array.

Comment: Please check if that.locations array is valid, I tested with the array variable, still works, I will update the reply with array variable.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why it's not working.  ```Array.isArray(that.locations)``` returns true